# odom frame changes hight

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

i have a short question about the odom frame.

How is the wanted behaviour of it ?

My Problem is my odom frames changes it hight all time

it is: 0.31 -> 0.12 -> 0.25 -> 0.31 -> 0.12 .....

Is that the behaviour it should it keep it hight?
The UAV is not moving, it just stand on the ground.
The x and y coordinate are stable

Can someone please explain me how the odom frame should act ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67533/odom-frame-changes-hight/) by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on ROS Answers with karma: 336 on 2013-07-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on 2013-07-17**:
Your odom frame is defined w.r.t to which frame?? Check that because any change in parent frame can effect the child frame..

**Comment by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on 2013-07-17**:
the TF tree ist map -> odom -> base_footprint -> ...
The map frame is stable. And the base footprint follows the jumps of the odom frame

**Comment by [glukon](https://answers.ros.org/users/31987/glukon/) on 2017-09-25**:
Hey, I would take a look on the encoder values. Maybe the base_footprint is coupled to the encoders. At kobuki-base I had some problems first, because I did not know that then jump after reaching ~6500 or so. But code would be even more useful - please post some :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Look at the odom values and see what is causing those jumps and also look at corresponding velocities in odom values.

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0